# How to search in every field of subdocument

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my document:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5259b73b4949e0b22608960d"), "array" : [  "a",  "b" ] }
```

To find some value in the `array` field I use the following query:

```
db.collection.find({roles: 'a'})
```

But I faced the problem, when the `array` field looks like this:

```
{ "array": { '0': 'a', '1' : 'b' } }
```

How can I do the same query as before with such kind of array (which actually is a subdocument where all fields are array indexes)?
So I need to find a document, where ANY of subdocument's fields equals to something.

Unfortunately, I can't change this field, because it is generated by a 3rd side API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a better choice than to use [the `$where` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), which allows you to filter the collection by specifying a custom JavaScript function.

Please note that for large collections this could pose a performance problem, since `$where` conditions cannot take advantage of indexes.

OK, back to the problem: In the `{ "array": { '0': 'a', '1' : 'b' } }` literal, `array` is not technically an array, but an object with the properties `'0'`, `'1'`, and `'2'`.

Assuming that all `array` objects will have a continuous list of properties starting at `'0'`, you could iterate until you find either a match, or a number `i` for which `array[i]` is `undefined` (signifying the end of the continuous property sequence).

The JavaScript function that achieves this is:

```js
function () {
    for(var i = 0; this.array[i] !== undefined; i++) {
        if(this.array[i] === 'b') {
            return true;
        }
    } 

    return false; 
}
```

To easily paste it into the Mongo shell, here's the one-line version:

```js
function () {for(var i=0; this.array[i]!==undefined; i++) {if(this.array[i]==='b') {return true; } } return false; }
```

Note two things about the script above:

- `this.array` should be changed if the property has a name different than `"array"`
- `'b'` is the value to search for in the *"array"*. Change this to whatever it is the you're searching for.

So, using the script above, this is what you could write in the Mongo shell:

```js
db.arraycollection.find({$where: function() {for(var i=0; this.array[i]!==undefined; i++) {if(this.array[i]==='b') {return true; } } return false; }});
```

To simplify things a bit, since this is the only condition of the `find()`, we can omit the `$where` altogether, leaving just the js function as a parameter:

```js
db.arraycollection.find(function() {for(var i=0; this.array[i]!==undefined; i++) {if(this.array[i]==='b') {return true; } } return false; });
```

PS: *Sorry for the long lines above that make you scroll, but I thought the one-liners are more convenient to paste in the Mongo shell.*

Answer (score 0):

You can find subdocuments of array using [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) :

```
db.collection.find( { "_id" : ObjectId("5259b73b4949e0b22608960d") },
             { array: { $elemMatch: { 0: '1'} } )
```

This will find the 'array' from your collection with particular object id, and the object of array matching { 0: '1'} object.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP is looking for a way to compare againsl *all* values in the array, not just the first.